# Why am I receiving this NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I encounter a NullPointerException on `clickCell[r][c] = false;` and on `new LifeGUI(new LifeModel(x, y, s);` and can't fix it. Please explain why this problem occurs and how I may fix it.

Code:

```
public  LifeModel(int rows, int cols, int cellSize) {
    row = rows;
    col = cols;
    cSize = cellSize;
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for ( int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
            clickCell[r][c] = false;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(int x, int y, int s) {
    new LifeGUI(new LifeModel(x, y, s));        
}
```

Comment: what is the type of clickCell?  looks like maybe you just didn't allocate it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the array object

```
boolean [][] clickCell = new boolean[rows][cols];
```

Add this command  before the for loop.

More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

If clickCell is declared somewhere else, the command should be:

```
clickCell = new boolean[rows][cols];
```

Or as GriffeyDog suggests, add the `new boolean[rows][cols]` at the place where you declare the array, depending on the logic of your program.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown where the `clickcell` array was declared, but likely you have declared it but not initialized it. You may have

```
boolean[][] clickcell;
```

but need:

```
boolean[][] clickcell = new boolean[rows][cols];
```

where `rows` and `cols` represent the size of the array you need.

Comment: Turns out you were right, such a simple mistake thank you for your help